# su to another user using ssh keys?

Tags: ssh, login, su

Assuming that `user_A` and `user_B` set up and exchange public ssh keys with 
each other, is it possible for `user_A` to `su` into `user_B` on the same machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to use `su` is usually controlled by `pam`, and has nothing to do with public key authentication as used with `ssh`.

Provided the public key of `user_A` is in `user_B`'s `authorized_keys` file, all `user_A` needs to do is:

```
$ ssh user_B@localhost
```

It might the wording is not totally clear in your question, but private keys are not shared.